# Using react-infinite-calendar with css-modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-css-modules

I'd like to use [react-infinite-calendar](https://github.com/clauderic/react-infinite-calendar) component for a personal project. It's not picking up the css. I think my webpack configuration is the problem as I'm using [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules).

Could someone show me what I'd need to do to get it working?

My webpack configuration is:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: './dist/client/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        // https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: 'static/index.html'}
    ])
  ]
};
```

My date selector component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import InfiniteCalendar from 'react-infinite-calendar';
import 'react-infinite-calendar/styles.css'; // only needs to be imported once

import {TODAY} from '../../server/constants/date';

export default class DateSelector extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <InfiniteCalendar
        width={400}
        height={600}
        selectedDate={TODAY}
        maxDate={TODAY}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by having to separate webpack loaders for locally scoped `css-modules` and globally scoped ones. My webpack configuration is below and so for css modules I've had to name the files so they end with `.module.css`.

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: './dist/client/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        // https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules
        test: /\.module.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      },
      {
        test: /^((?!\.module).)*css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: 'static/index.html'}
    ])
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to exclude `react-infinite-calendar` from your CSS module loader and include it in the standard CSS loader.

That way you don't have to rename all of your CSS files.

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /react-infinite-calendar/,
    loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: /react-infinite-calendar/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
  },
]
```